# AWS Cognito forgotPassword returns request aborted

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm build a React web client using AWS Cognito for user management. I'm using the [amazon-cognito-identity-js library](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) for this.

Login and sign up work fine.

Now, I'm unable to implement **Use case 12**: Starting and completing a forgot password flow for an unauthenticated user:

```
var cognitoUser = getCognitoUser({
  Username : this.state.email //email from React component state
});
cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
  onSuccess: function (result) {
    console.log('call result: ' + result);
  },
  onFailure: function(err) {
    console.log("failed", err);
    alert(err);
  },
  inputVerificationCode() {
    var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ' ,'');
    var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');
    cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
  }
});
```

getCognitoUser

```
function getCognitoUser(userData) {
  userData.Pool = getUserPool();
  return new CognitoUser(userData);
}
```

getUserPool

```
function getUserPool() {
  return new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
  });
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I type as an email, **onFailure** is called and I get a "RequestAbortedError: Request aborted" error.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong or how to get a better error message?

Answer (score 1):

This actually works, I just forgot the `event.preventDefault();` in the beginning of my click handler